# What are the iptables command to enable docker network

Tags: iptables, docker

I am on a debian like os and I decided to start my iptable filter from scratch, I droped everithing with this command:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X 
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But With this config I cannot start my docker container. In my container I have got a nginx server, a php-fpm and a mysql database. so when I run

`docker compose up`

I have got

> Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint front_orcieres (d6e7efba20b11de242cbb40772697857e13ef11e42b567f3b39b3577ce6615e0):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i br-283b29a6561f -o br-283b29a6561f -p tcp -d 172.19.0.7 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
> (exit status 1))

I know that there are some existing rules for the docker network to work on a device, I would like to know the Iptables command to generate the proper filter table for docker

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

When you restart the docker service it automatically recreates the proper iptables rules